# Android Designing a custom view

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-recyclerview

Good day,

I am working on an application, and I want to design the view below, I am unsure which view to use.

From my experience with Android development, I'm thinking it should be a list view or a recyclerview with a custom header, I may be wrong, but looking at the view could someone explain what view I should use. I have red arrows indicating what I am talking about.

I was thinking a custom scrollable list view, and defining the list of items, shown by the three arrows, basically three custom list items.

Should it be a list view or recyclerview with a custom header for the arrow marked as 1.

Should the arrow marked as 3. be a gridview that's filled dynamically? As I understand it, the gridview doesn't work well with a scrollable parent, like a listview, as I want the whole view to scroll based on the content, like in  Instagram, what is a good approach to accomplish this.

I came here because I have searched and really couldn't find any good advice

Thanks in advance

[image: Implement View Like Instagram]

Comment: Will there be multiple such profiles(Including 1, 2, 3) one below the other or only one?

Comment: One below the other so list row 1 on would be like the arrow pointing to number 1, then list row 2 would be like the arrow by arrow 2, then list row 3 would be like the arrow at three which populates a grid of images from a backend so it could grow, but the whole parent view would be scrollable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't need one single `RecyclerView` here. You can use a combination of `ViewGroup`s and `View`s. Simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Code for 1,2-->

        <!-- Your grid from 3-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Edit:**

Also do this on your `RecyclerView`: `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`.

This will make your whole layout scrollable, while your `RecyclerView`, having a height of `wrap_content` will just expand(adding to the height of the whole layout) without the need for internal scrolling.

Comment: Thanks @Veneet I will give hat a shot.

Comment: @VeneetReddy  How to make the 1 and 2 layout scroll without having them in a ScrollView or RecyclerView ?

Comment: @AhmedAbidi Check my edited answer. Should work if I got your requirements correctly.

Comment: @VeneetReddy Having this : the recyclerView in a scroll view. It prevents the recycling from happening.